# Building a Room Database object causes "Force finishing activity"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

**Can I open a Room database from a Android NotificationListenerService?**

When I try to open the database in the NotificationListenerService my app crashes, saying

```
W/ActivityManager: Force finishing activity com.xyz.abc.notificationmanager/.MainActivity
W/InputDispatcher: channel '79ec910 com.xyz.abc.notificationmanager/com.xyz.abc.notificationmanager.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher: channel '79ec910 com.xyz.abc.notificationmanager/com.xyz.abc.notificationmanager.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

**What do these errors mean?**

If I remove the inMemoryDatabaseBuilder line it works fine. I originally started with a regular databaseBuilder but I'm trying the in memory one just in case that was the problem (which it doesn't appear to be).

It does not crash if I simply `val db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(applicationContext, TheDatabase::class.java)` without `.build()`ing it.

**The code:**

Database:

```
package com.xyz.abc.notificationmanager
import android.arch.persistence.room.*

@Entity(tableName="matches")
class SettingsMatch {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate=true)
    var id: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name="package_name")
    var packageName: String? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name="group_id")
    var groupId: Long? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name="comment")
    var comment: String? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name="search_title")
    var searchTitle: String? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name="search_content")
    var searchContent: String? = null
}

@Entity(tableName="groups", foreignKeys=arrayOf(
    ForeignKey(entity=SettingsMatch::class, parentColumns=arrayOf("id"), childColumns=arrayOf("group_id"))
))
class SettingsGroup {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate=true)
    var id: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name="comment")
    var comment: String? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name="min_secs_between_alerts")
    var minSecsBetweenAlerts: Int = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name="last_alert_time")
    var lastAlertTime: Int = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name="alert_when_screen_on")
    var alertWhenScreenOn: Boolean = true

    @ColumnInfo(name="volume_percent")
    var volumePercent: Int = 100

    @ColumnInfo(name="vibration_pattern")
    var vibrationPattern: LongArray = longArrayOf(0)
}

@Dao
interface SettingsMatchDao {
    @get:Query("SELECT * FROM matches")
    val all: List<SettingsMatch>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM matches WHERE package_name=:packageName")
    fun loadAllByPackageName(packageName: String): List<SettingsMatch>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM matches "
            + "WHERE package_name=:packageName AND "
            + "(:searchTitle LIKE CONCAT('%', search_title, '%') OR :searchContent LIKE CONCAT('%', search_content, '%')) "
            + "LIMIT 1")
    fun loadByPackageNameTitleContent(packageName: String, searchTitle: String, searchContent: String): SettingsMatch

    @Insert
    fun insert(settingsMatch: SettingsMatch): Long

    @Delete
    fun delete(settingsMatch: SettingsMatch)
}

@Dao
interface SettingsGroupDao {
    @get:Query("SELECT * FROM groups")
    val all: List<SettingsGroup>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1")
    fun loadByGroupId(id: Int): SettingsGroup

    @Query("SELECT * FROM groups "
            + "INNER JOIN matches ON matches.group_id = groups.id "
            + "WHERE package_name=:packageName AND "
            + "(:searchTitle LIKE CONCAT('%', search_title, '%') OR :searchContent LIKE CONCAT('%', search_content, '%')) "
            + "LIMIT 1")
    fun loadByPackageNameTitleContent(packageName: String, searchTitle: String, searchContent: String): SettingsGroup

    @Insert
    fun insert(settingsGroup: SettingsGroup): Long

    @Delete
    fun delete(settingsGroup: SettingsGroup)
}

@Database(entities=arrayOf(SettingsMatch::class, SettingsGroup::class), version=1)
abstract class TheDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun matchDao(): SettingsMatchDao
    abstract fun groupDao(): SettingsGroupDao
}
```

NotificationListenerService:

```
class NotificationManagerService : NotificationListenerService() {
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return super.onBind(intent)
    }

    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        /** This is the troublesome line **/
        val db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(applicationContext, TheDatabase::class.java).build()
        db.close()
    }

    override fun onNotificationRemoved(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {

    }
}
```

Comment: getting the `context` from within a `service` may work differently.